# Need help to design a reverse mosfet/transistor switch

Tags: transistors, switches

I have an accelerometer kind of sensor which gives analog voltage at level of uV-mVs. I want to read voltage values from it with a MCU. I am expecting it will not give more than 0.2 V in normal conditions. So I designed an amplifier where 0.2 V gives 3.3 V at the amplifier output. But there is a minimal chance that it can pass 0.2 V .To eliminate values over 0.2V, V I want to design a reverse mosfet/transistor switch. How can I achieve this?

Thank you from now.

Comment: What do you mean by "reverse mosfet/transistor switch"? Could your problem be solved more simply with just a 3.6 V zener at the amplfier output?

Comment: I just want give 0 V to MCU when sensor gives more than 0.2 V. I though it can be possible with "reverse mosfet/transistor switch". But anything will be okay.

Comment: Would it be okay to just give 3.3(ish) V to the ADC for high input voltages, instead of 0 V? If you translate over-range inputs to 0 V, how will you distinguish them from actual 0 V inputs?

Comment: Yes, it can be okay too. I will give values over 0.2 V to directly to MCU to say that sensor is giving too high results.

Comment: By the way, your question demonstrates the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/). Instead of asking how to implement a particular solution that might not be ideal, it's better to simply explain the problem you're actually trying to solve so that others can suggest a variety of solutions you might not have thought of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this with a simple zener diode voltage limiter, placed after the amplifier stage:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkwPZS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

D1 will start to conduct if the op-amp tries to drive the output voltage above about 3.6 V. R3 will limit the current in to the zener and/or ADC in this situation.

Generally the zener voltage might vary by a couple hundred mV, so a 3.6 V zener is needed to ensure the circuit doesn't start to limit below 3.3 V. A 3.6 V limit is generally low enough to prevent damage to the ADC if it's powered by 3.3 V.

With an additional capacitor in parallel with the zener, R3 can do double duty as current limiting for the limiter circuit and R3/C can form an antialiasing filter for the ADC.

Comment: What should be the value of R3?

Comment: High enough so that even with maximum input voltage, the current through the zener is not above its maximum current. Low enough so that it doesn't filter out high frequencies you want to detect or disturb the ADC reading. So it depends on the specs of the zener you choose and your ADC.